# Play 2.2 - specs2 - How to test futures in play 2.2?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, future, specs2, playframework-2.2

my way of testing futures was using value1. 
I migrated to play2.2. I found out, my accustomed way to test is gone.
@scala.deprecated("Use scala.concurrent.Promise instead.", "2.2")

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oliver

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement the PlaySpecification trait as described in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTest). This trait provides a method await. You can also override the default timeout.

```
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class FooSpec extends PlaySpecification {
   override implicit def defaultAwaitTimeout: Timeout = 20.seconds

   "foo" should {
     "handle futures" {
        val result = await(Future(true))

        result should beTrue
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also override the default timeout for a single test scenario, like so:

```
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class FooSpec {
   "foo" should {
     "handle futures" with DefaultAwaitTimeout {
        override implicit def defaultAwaitTimeout: Timeout = 20.seconds
        val result = await(Future(true))

        result should beTrue
     }
   }
}
```

To stop your code at a specific position, use

```
 Thread.sleep(milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

From play 2.4~, ,`play.api.test.Helpers._` provides few utilities such as `contentAsJson`, `contentAsString` and `contentAsBytes` which can be used if you are waiting for a `Future` of type `play.api.mvc.Result`. This takes care of the waiting but you still need to set the implicit timeout value.